# Fastest way to pass a file's contents from Kernel to User mode?

Tags: windows, filter, kernel, driver, wdk

I'll try to be brief, but fully descriptive:

This is Windows-specific. Using the Windows Driver Development Kit (DDK).

I am writing a Kernel Mode Driver (KMD) for the first time, having no prior experience in Kernel Mode. I am playing around currently with the "scanner" mini-filter sample which comes with the DDK, and expanding upon it for practice. The "scanner" mini-filter is a basic outline for a generic "anti-virus" type scanning driver which hooks file creates/closes and operates on the associated file to scan for a "bad word" before approving/denying the requested operation.

The end goal is to scan the file with the user-mode application when it is opened, deciding whether or not the mini-filter should allow the operation to complete, without noticeable slow-down to the process or user which is attempting to open the file. I will also want to scan the entire file again when a save is attempted to decide whether or not to allow the save to complete successfully or deny the save. The mini-filter sample lays out the groundwork for how to hook these calls, but is a bit weak in the actually "scanning" portion.

I am looking at expanding the sample to scan the entire file that has been opened, such as to generate a hash, rather than just the first 1k (the sample's limit). I have modified the sample to read the entirety of the file and send it using the same mechanisms within the original sample. This method uses `FltReadFile` to read the file within the KMD and `FltSendMessage` to send the buffer to the user-mode component. The user-mode application is using `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` to grab the notifications from the KMD and process the buffers.

However, I'm noticing that this process seems to be pretty slow compared to a normal open/read in C++ using the standard library (fstream). This method is taking between approximately 4-8 times longer than simplying opening and reading the file in a simple C++ user app. I have adjusted buffer sizes to see if it makes for a noticeable improvement, and while it can help slightly, the benefits have not appeared to be very significant.

Since I am looking to scan files in 'real-time', this rate of transfer is highly disappointing and prohibitive. Is there a faster way to transfer a file's contents from a Kernel-Mode Driver to a User-Mode Application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can suggest several solutions:

1. Use DeviceIoControl with METHOD_OUT_DIRECT transfer type to pass large amounts of data.
2. Create memory section and map it to your process (remember about limited address space on 32-bit platforms).
3. Pass file path to your application and open it there.

Comment: I've been distracted and unable to actually attempt to implement this just yet, but the information looks very promising and is much appreciated. Thanks!